# How can I install tensorflow in my laptop which has AMD Radeon (TM) graphics?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

My laptop lenovo has AMD Radeon (TM) graphics and I am trying to install tensorflow but I always get an error when I code this:

```
import os

os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"

import tensorflow as tf

physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

the error is :

```
 tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

 IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I do to correctly install tensorflow?

I am using pycharm as an IDE

Comment: Maybe the [official instructions](https://rocm.docs.amd.com/projects/install-on-linux/en/latest/how-to/3rd-party/tensorflow-install.html) how to install tensorflow with AMD can help

Answer (score 0):

You can try below instructions to install tensorflow in your laptop...

```
pip install tensorflow-rocm
```

Then check is it install perfectly or not...

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

After that you can check your code. Hopefully it will be work.

Comment: It did not work at all, I firstly installed visual , CUDA, NVIDIA cuDNN and finally anaconda but I kept having the issue and then I read something in which it says that tensorflow does not support AMD Radeon (TM) graphics so what should I do?

Comment: Yes, I understand the issue. I also faced the same issue a couple of months ago, and then I started using Google Colab. You can also use Google Colab.

Comment: Yeah but in google colab did not work at all , I still have the same issue , I do not know how you fixed it, how did you do it?

Comment: Did you configure colab to use a GPU?  Default it uses only CPU.

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: I just changed CPU for GPU and it worked perfectly, it was awesome , thanks so much :)